# Preventing jQuery fadeOut from changing object to display:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a lightbox type thing and I'm using jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` features to show the enlarged `div` elements.  However, when I call `fadeOut` on the enlarged `div` the smaller one also disappears because `fadeOut` sets `display: none` upon completion.  Is there a way to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` a copy of a div without affecting the original?  Keep in mind that this `div` does not contain an image, rather it holds a large set of other `divs` and text.

Here's my current jQuery:

```
$("#magnify").on("click", function(event){
    $("#black-overlay").addClass("show");
    $(".close").addClass("show");
    $("#inner-box").addClass("enlarge").fadeIn(600);
});

$(".close").on("click", function(event){
    $("#inner-box").fadeOut(600);
});
```

The HTML is long, so I stripped it down for you, but I want everything inside `inner-box` to enlarge **AND**  `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` when certain elements are clicked:

```
<div id="outter-box" class="activeSlide">
    <div id="magnify"><a href="#"><p>Enlarge</p></a></div><!--/#magnify-->

    <div id="inner-box">    
        <div class="close">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/close.gif" width="22px" height="22px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="inside">
                <p>A buttload of stuff in here</p>
            </div><!--/.inside-->
        </div><!--/#content-->
    </div><!--/.inner-box-->
</div><!--/#outter-box-->
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML structure as well as the jQuery?

Comment: You can't prevent it, use [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try :

```
.animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
```

I'm not sure about browser prefixed properties though, but this might work :

```
.animate({MozOpacity: 0}, 400); // Firefox
.animate({WebkitOpacity: 0}, 400); // Chrome, Safari
.animate({OOpacity: 0}, 400); // Opera
.animate({msOpacity: 0}, 400); // Internet Explorer
```

Comment: opacity doesn't need to be prefixed. Older IE uses filters.

Comment: `.animate()` handles all the vendor-specific prefixes. No need to do them on your own.

Comment: The problem with this is that it will set the opacity of my original object to 0 as well.  I would like to make a copy of my original object, and alter the opacity of the copied version, without affecting the opacity of the original.

Comment: .clone().animate({opacity: 0}, 400);